# X11VNC 0.9.13 broken on Debian Buster

Tags: x11vnc

I used X11VNC to mirror my X11 Session succesfully since years on Debian 9. However the version (0.9.13) in Debian 10 does not seem to work anymore. The X11 process eats up all resources periodically rendering the system extremely slow.
On a test system the testing version of bullseye with X11VNC (0.9.16) it seems to be fixed. Any chance to get this version installed on Buster?

Comment: would a downgrade work? There isn't much functionality added. If the problem was not present in stretch ... Otherwise you'd have to backport the bullseye version (it's not that difficult, but it takes time).

Comment: I need to stick to buster :-( How do I backport the bullseye version?

Comment: See the answer. Note that I meant to downgrade **just** `x11vnc` / `x11vnc-data`, not the whole system.

Comment: came across this and i'm in the same boat, needing to stick with a Buster OS.  which solution did you go with?  or has it been retro-fixed?  having some trouble with x11vnc, so i'm curious.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of possibilities.

**Downgrade package**

In this particular case, after checking the differences and changes in dependencies between the versions, I would (try to) downgrade just `x11vnc` and `x11vnc-data` by installing those packages.

Get the deb package for your architecture for [x11vnc](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/x11vnc) and for [x11vnc-data](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/x11vnc-data).

And then run:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i x11vnc-data_0.9.13-2+deb9u2_all.deb x11vnc_0.9.13-2+deb9u2_amd64.deb
```

**Backport package**

This is the general solution, but it is not always possible and you might have to tweak dependencies. It also might be straightforward, it depends on the package and its dependencies. For this package, it should go pretty smoothly.

Debian has a document on how to do that. Check [Simple backport creation](https://wiki.debian.org/SimpleBackportCreation).

Answer (score 0):

Run `x11vnc` as follow :

```
x11vnc -gui tray=setpass -rfbport PROMPT -bg
```